# Where can I find a high-res PNG with transparency or a vector version of the new Ubuntu GNOME logo?

Tags: gnome, logo, vector-drawings

Could someone point me to where I can find a high-res PNG over transparent background, or even better, a vector version of the new Ubuntu GNOME logo?

I can't seem to find one.

[image: The new Ubuntu GNOME logo.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the SVG and PNG (24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, and 256x256) files of the Ubuntu GNOME logo at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics. Specifically:

SVG (cannot be uploaded to Ask Ubuntu unfortunately): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel.svg

[24x24](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel24.png):

[image]

[48x48](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel48.png):

[image]

[96x96](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel96.png):

[image]

[128x128](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel128.png):

[image]

[256x256](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Graphics?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roundel256.png):

[image]